# cfmail is not working with google app if there are more than one address

Tags: google-app-engine, coldfusion, gmail, google-apps, cfmail

currently we moved our mail server. We are using Google App. I made changes in ColdFusion admin; mail server: 'aspmx.l.google.com' and port: 25 .

If I am using following code; its working fine.

```
<cfmail to="abc@xyz.com" from="def@xyz.com" subject="Hello">
Email Body
</cfmail>
```

If I add any 'BCC' or 'CC'; cfmail wont work and it does not throw any error(there is syntax error). In-fact if I add extra email in 'TO' with coma; it still wont work.

In short if I am using single address it works fine; but if I use multiple address it wont work.

I am not sure if it is ColdFusion related issue or google app.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what does your mail.log say? Are you logging sent messages? Is there anything in your Undelivr folder?

Comment: mailsent.log givessuccessful message. And there is no error on mail.log.

Comment: Then it's not a CF issue.